# How to disable default payment method (Credit Card) in Stripe Checkout

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I need only one Payment Method (AliPay). But I can't disable default payment method with Stripe Checkout (Credit Card). Of course, I read [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout), but I don't have any idea how I can make that.

This is My code.

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'public_key',
    alipay: true,
    locale: false,
    currency: "usd",
    token: function(token) {
        // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
});

handler.open({
    name: 'example.com',
    description: 'AliPay Payment',
    amount: 10000
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to disable the default (card) area of Checkout.

If you're looking for greater customizability of your payment form I'd have a look at Stripe.js/Elements and the Sources API. You can use the Sources 
 to generate an AliPay source, redirect a user to AliPay to authorize a payment, and then return them to your site, https://stripe.com/docs/sources/alipay

Answer (score 0):

The credit cards payment can be disabled via the [API](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_method_configurations/update), e.g.:

```bash
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_method_configurations/pmc_123 \
        -d "card[display_preference][preference]"=off
```